# Parameter concatenation in dynamic SQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I want to update a row via Pl/pgSQL in PostgreSQL but an error occurs. This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Surrogate_Del"(tablename text, surro uuid)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$DECLARE
tblname text;
surrogate uuid;
BEGIN
tblname:=tablename;
surrogate:=surro;
execute 'UPDATE'||tblname||'SET ID=NULL WHERE surrogate='||surrogate|| ;
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

This is the UUID that I want to update record base on it

```
*syntax Error »ab7«
cd32cdf0-5ab7-11e2-abda-1c4bd605a98d
                  ^*
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you are missing spaces after update and before set: `'UPDATE '||tblname||' SET ...`

Comment: I edited my query but the error remains

Comment: Please include again your updated code and whatever the new error message is.  Your update will have solved one syntax error, and now you have another.

Comment: Is this intended for repeated use or a one-time operation? For ad-hoc use, consider a [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-do.html) command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need escaped quotes around the parameter:

```
execute 'UPDATE ' || tblname || ' SET ID = NULL WHERE surrogate = ''' || surrogate || '''';
```

mu's suggestion is cleaner and more robust:

```
execute 'UPDATE ' || tblname || ' SET ID = NULL WHERE surrogate = ' || quote_literal(surrogate);
```

If it is a newer version of postgresql (9.0+ I guess) you can use the `format` function:

```
execute format('UPDATE %I SET ID = NULL WHERE surrogate = %L', tblname, surrogate);
```

`%L` escapes it as a SQL literal.

Answer (score 4):

The generally superior approach is to [insert ***values*** with a **`USING`** clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). This avoids the run-time overhead of casting to `text` and back and possible hazards with quoting special characters.

You can also use your *named parameters* directly. No point in declaring and assigning another layer of local variables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION surrogate_del (_tblname text, _surro uuid)
   RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I SET ID = NULL WHERE surrogate = $1', _tblname)
   USING _surro;
END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I also converted your function name to lower case and removed the double-quotes. My personal advice is to *never* use CamelCase identifiers in PostgreSQL. That's a constant source of pain.

On a related note: remember to provide the table name `_tblname` in a case sensitive fashion. [`format()` or `quote_ident()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) preserve the spelling verbatim.